# Buiding TABS with Quicktabs, Views and Entity References

Tags: nodes, blocks

I'm trying to build a tabbed content for node using  [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference)  , [Quicktabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs) and Views in this way:

1- Create 2 content type: **simple-page** and **tab**

2- In **simple-page** content type I added a entityreference field to reference **tab** node

3- I created a **simple-page** and inside it I added 3 **tab** nodes

So far so good.Now I want to show this **tab** nodes as tabs. The title of the node will be the tab title and the body will be the content of the tab.

Now, I know that I can create a Quicktab instance which can take the Title and the Content of each tab from Views

The idea is to create the View with 2 blocks, one for the title and one for the body of the referenced **tab** node. But I don't know how to do it. I need help to buil this view blocks.

Then after I will add a contextual filter set to the NID in the url. 
Lastly I will put the Quicktab instance block in the node so that I can get only the **tab** pages referenced for that node.

Comment: Why do you need 2 blocks etc? Can't you just [display related nodes as field of "tab" node](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewfield)?

Comment: And then, can I buil the quickinstance? My idea is based in this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hjs4uPB7L1I the problem is that the tutorial uses fieds and I need to use references nodes

Comment: @Mołot can you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: It was just an broad idea, not an answer. I'm not quite sure if I understand what you need.

Comment: @Mołot what I need is to create a block to be shown in basic pages. This block will show tabbed content. The title and content of each tab is provided by a field of basic pages which is a Node Reference field. The title of the tab will be the title of the referenced node. The content of the tab will be the body of the referenced node.